# Excel - Summing up consecutive values based on drop-down selection

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a Values like

```
Month      Price
 Jan        10
 Feb        20
 Mar        30
 ............
 Dec        50
```

I have a dropdown for selecting month 
 If user pickedup the month Feb
 then the sum should be displayed as 30

Help me out ! tried a lot with excel function ended up with frustration

Comment: Did you try `SUMIF`? It should be easy to use it to do what your trying. Although maybe I'm missing something since your sample looks like Feb should sum to 20.

Comment: tried but failed. Feb value should be jan price + feb price here ie, 10+20 =30 for Feb

Comment: I see. I forgot about the "Consecutive" in the title.

Comment: Is it always just 12 months in order in that column? I can't answer now, but if so I'd suggest looking at the `INDEX` function. If not, you need to describe it more.

Comment: yup I look that . Meanwhile If u guys got answer plz post it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very interesting idea.

[image]

Formula in B1 `=SUM(INDIRECT("E1:E"&MATCH(A1,D:D,0)))`

Hope this will help you.

`A     B  C   D      E
Feb   30    Month   Price
            Jan     10
            Feb     20
            Mar     30
            Apr     40
            May     50
            Jun     60
            Jul     70
            Aug     80
            Sep     90
            Oct     100
            Nov     110
            Dec     120`

Comment: cant able to see the image

Comment: Is it possible to sent attachment file

Comment: How to sent attachment file?

Comment: That's a good solution! `indirect` is excel's magic wand. upvote!

Comment: can u send the doc to lathaab2w@hotmail.com

Comment: @SQLPolice, Here's an alternative you might like using `INDEX/MATCH`. It's generally preferred over `INDIRECT` because `INDIRECT` is volatile: `=SUM(E1:INDEX(E:E,MATCH(A1,D:D,0)))`